# Heroku fails Precompiling assets when deploying due to differences in Node version. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 5.2 app into Heroku but I get the error:

```
"Precompiling assets failed"`
```

because of this other error:

```
error upath@1.0.4: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=4 <=9". Got "10.14.1"
```

The issue happens just after Heroku Buildpack attempts to install Yarn (v1.12.3).

I've noticed that the Buildpack installs `node-v10.14.1-linux-x64` and thus creating this incompatible version error. However, I can't find how to make Heroku install a previous version of Node.

I've tried:
Solutions posted in StackOverflow, usually solving a similar issue for people trying to deploy Node apps. The solution involves specifying a Node version (to one that matches Heroku) in `package.json` file. I've tried something similar adding a Node property with a lower version in package.json hoping to influence the Node version Heroku installs without any success.

I assume then what would make sense is to change Node version in Heroku Buildpack (see Update bellow) but I can't find how to do it and it seems somewhat burdensome to do this with a simple Heroku deploy with a vanilla app.

I wonder **what could have caused this issue** and would appreciate any guidance on how to solve it.

**[UPDATE]**

So I've managed to solve the issue customising Heroku's Buildpack for Ruby and changing Node's installing version by:

(1) Forking heroku-buildpack-ruby-master

(2) Editing Node version to match that of my local host at: `heroku-buildpack-ruby-master/lib/language_pack/helpers/nodebin.rb`

(3) Setting this edited buildpack as the default for Heroku deployments in my terminal doing `$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/my_git_hub/heroku-buildpack-ruby-mod`

(4) Deploying to Heroku

This solves the issue. Still don't know why this happened if I haven't had this problem while deploying any other Rails App to Heroku .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to solve the issue customising Heroku's Buildpack for Ruby and changing Node's installing version by:

(1) Forking heroku-buildpack-ruby-master

(2) Editing Node version to match that of my local host at: heroku-buildpack-ruby-master/lib/language_pack/helpers/nodebin.rb

(3) Setting this edited buildpack as the default for Heroku deployments in my terminal doing $ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/my_git_hub/heroku-buildpack-ruby-mod

(4) Deploying to Heroku

This solves the issue. Still don't know why this happened if I haven't had this problem while deploying any other Rails App to Heroku .

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting with the same issue. 
[Deploy to Heroku failed. move-file incompatible with node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758641/deploy-to-heroku-failed-move-file-incompatible-with-node-version)

I realized that the order of the buildpack binaries matters. I had the same error message and in my case what fixed it was to determine that nodejs should be executed first, then the ruby buildpack. There is some documentation on this here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#installed-binaries